# Problems related to accessing css modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack.config.js

why am I getting an error while accessing CSS modules such as localIdentName in my webpack.config.js? and why am I not getting separate production and development webpack in my react app?

The initial stage of webpack error getting after embedding `modules: true` and `localeIdentName`

[image: initial stage of webpack error getting after embedding modules: true and localeIdentName]

Comment: Do you use a regular React app or CRA?

Comment: i am using CRA .